# DbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations() always empty

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, ef-code-first, dbmigrator

I'm using the `DbMigrator` class to get a list of pending migrations. For some reason it returns no items even though there are pending migrations. Am i missing a step?

```
var configuration = new Migrations.Configuration();
configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo("MyDatabase");

var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
var migs = migrator.GetPendingMigrations().ToList();
Console.WriteLine(migrator.GetPendingMigrations().ToString());
```

I thought it might be the connection string but what's interesting is that `migrator.GetDatabaseMigrations()` returns the correct list of migrations already applied to the db.

Answer (score 4):

The same happened to me and the reason was that I was working in a different assembly. In that case, you need to specify the assembly and namespace that contains your migrations:

```
config.MigrationsAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof([One of your migration classes]));
config.MigrationsNamespace = "[Namespace containing your migrations]";
```

Comment: Any ideas why migrator.GetPendingMigrations() doesn't sees the migrations already applied for that database?

Comment: @DudumanBogdanVlad: As the name implies, pending migrations are migrations that are still waiting to be applied. I'm not sure if the `DbMigrator` can show you already applied migrations. You can always find them in the __migrationhistory table in the database, though.

Comment: @DudumanBogdanVlad Looks like the `DbMigrator.GetDatabaseMigrations()` method should get you the applied migrations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrator.getdatabasemigrations(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.GetDatabaseMigrations

Answer (score 4):

I have same problem too, and after a week of research and read .Net source finally find solution.
If you working in a different assembly, you mus set configuration assembly information completely like this:

```
    public void UpdateDatabaseToLatestVersion()
    {
        var configuration = new DbMigrationsConfiguration();
        var type = GetType();

        configuration.MigrationsAssembly = type.Assembly;
        configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(connectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient");
        configuration.MigrationsNamespace = type.Namespace + ".Migrations";
        configuration.ContextKey = type.Namespace + ".Migrations.Configuration";
        configuration.ContextType = type;
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);

        migrator.Update();
     }
```

This code is in `DbContextBase` class, All `DbContext` in my project inherit `DbContextBase`. `DbContextBase` is abstract and it is located in another assembly. When called `UpdateDatabaseToLatestVersion` from each DbContext, `var type = GetType();` return inherited DbContext type.

Comment: Almost 4 years later, this was the answer needed. When Automatic migrations are disabled, and you need a way for a pipeline to do the migrations without having to run "update-database", then this is the way to go!

Answer (score -1):

I arrived at his question when trying to solve this in Entity framework core. Posting how I fixed it in case someone else also randomly gets to this question trying to solve this.

This is the solution on how to fix this in EF Core.

I added this Extension method to my code

```
public static IApplicationBuilder MigrateDatabase(this IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
{
    using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        db.Database.EnsureCreated(); // this was my problem. If the database was missing, then the migrations were never applied.

        var migrations = db.Database.GetPendingMigrations();
        if (migrations.Any())
            db.Database.Migrate();
    }

    return app;
}
```

And I call it in Startup.cs from

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
{
    // other things here
    app.MigrateDatabase(scopeFactory);
}
```